# Change color of Google Maps circle by running through loop

Tags: google-maps, geometry

I have a function to output color as below:

```
function sortAQI(aqi){
var result;
if (aqi <= 350) {
    result="\'green\'";

}
if ((aqi <= 425) && (aqi > 350)) {
result="\'yellow\'";

}
if (aqi > 425){
    result="\'red\'";

}return result;}
```

I use alert and the output is fine, but when I run it through the loop, the circles are all black. Below is my code:

`for (i = 0; i < jsarr_aqi.length; i++){
    var colorCircle = sortAQI(parseInt(jsarr_aqi[i]));
    var circleHeat = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: colorCircle,
        fillOpacity:0.1,
        map:map,
        center: {lat:parseFloat(jsarr_lat[i]),lng:parseFloat(jsarr_long[i])},
        radius: 1

})`
I turn on the console but nothing shown.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (with sample data for  all the arrays).

Comment: Maybe make the return value from sortAQI a string (`green` rather than "'green'")

Comment: I would first try as suggested above: remove the double quotes and escaping, something like `result = "green"`. You say that there is nothing in the console but I see no use of the console in your code. So please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need further help with that.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Ha! That works! I make things complicated myself. Thanks for clearing out my mind!